Adding labels about boxed nodes in tikz pictures
I need something roughly along the following figure:

I managed to this in tikz:
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth'}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{\textsubscript{\scriptsize\textrm{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.8cm,align=left]
%relative placement of nodes starting from the bottom: x0-xastan-V0
\node[draw](Future-CP) at (0,0){Cat: V$'$  \\
                                   X0  < \emph{x{\^a}stan} <  V0\sub{past}};
\node[draw](Future)[above left of=Future-CP]{Cat: V$'$  \\
                                                \emph{x{\^a}stan-agr}  <  V0\sub{past}};
\node[draw](CPV0)[above right of=Future-CP]{Cat: V0  \\
                                               X0  <  V0\strut};

\node[above] at (Future-CP.north) {Future-CP};
\node[above] at (Future.north) {Future};
\node[above] at (CPV0.north) {CPV0};

% \draw[->] (Future) to (Future-CP.north west);
% \draw[->] (CPV0) to (Future-CP.north east);

\draw[->] (Future) to (Future-CP.north);
\draw[->] (CPV0) to (Future-CP.north);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Now the question is: How do get the arrows drawn so that they do not cross the node label? I tried north west and north east, but I would like the arrows to point more to the middle of the box. Just that they do not cross the label Future-CP.

([xshift=5mm]Future-CP.north west)? You could also give the label a name and use them in a coordinat specification (the calc library might make this easier: ($(Future-CP.north west)!.5!(<label>.south west)$) would place it halfway between the corners).

When your node is called (A), then these are equivalent: (A.north) and (A.90) etc. So your upper node could start the line at (A.290), while the lower could receive it at (A.130) or so.

Besides the suggestion from @Qrrbrbirlbel to move the label you can also move the arrows out of the way. Here are some alternatives for illustration.
However, I suggest you rework your code for more clarity, making it shorter, AND .... getting the math-modes right ... (I gave up on that one)

\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}

% simplified node names
% introduced missing math modes // what a mess ... (stopped this)
% attempts to make code more read-able ...

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth'}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{\textsubscript{\scriptsize\textrm{#1}}}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=2.8cm,
        align=left,
        A/.style={->,blue},
        B/.style={->,red},
 ]
    %relative placement of nodes starting from the bottom: x0-xastan-V0
    \node[draw](FC) at (0,0){
                        Cat: V$'$  \\
                        $X0  < \emph{x{\^a}stan} <  V0\sub{past}$};
    \node[draw](F)[above left of=FC]{
                        Cat: V$'$  \\
                        \emph{x{\^a}stan-agr}  <  V0\sub{past}};
    \node[draw](C)[above right of=FC]{
                        Cat: V0  \\ X0  <  V0\strut};
                    
    % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[above] at (FC.north)  {Future-CP};
    \node[above] at (F.north)   {Future};
    \node[above] at (C.north)   {CPV0};
    
    % ~~~ lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (F) to (FC.north);
    \draw[->] (C) -- (FC.north);
    
    % ~~~ some alternatives ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[A] (F.290) to (FC.160);
    \draw[A] (C.230) to (FC. 20);

    \draw[B] (F.south) to[out=290,in=180] (FC.west);
    \draw[B] (C.east)  to[out=  0,in=  0] (FC.east);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Since this is linguistics and not math, there's isn't much math mode at all, just the prime.
